# Remove faces inside object

Tags: edit-mode, faces, vertex-groups

So I have a cube coming back inside of another cube ( it's the trigger guard thing going inside the gun handle ) and I want it to not go inside ( merge with the handle ) thanks ! 
[image]

Comment: Hello, Rex, welcome. Please try and  put yourself in our shoes.We do not have the advantage of context, and so have no idea what the 'trigger guard' and 'gun handle' are. All _we_ see is a box and some stripes. Please illustrate from a meaningful angle, and explain very clearly what you mean by 'merge'.

Answer (score 0):

You can select individual faces in edit mode and delete them by pressing "X", then select "delete faces".

For this scenario you could also (with that face already selected)press "G" to grab and "Y" to lock it to the Y axis, then enable snap to faces and hover your mouse over the face that's black in the picture(it's normals appear to be inverted but that was not the question). .

Answer (score 0):

Move, along an axis and Snap To enabled, the opposite face that's inside. If the handle is sheared snap edges as well. Having done that you may remove the unnecessary face to save resources.